# Not fully implemented interfaces

Tags: typescript

Here is an example from the official documentation:

```
interface ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date;
    setTime(d: Date);
}

class Clock implements ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date;
    setTime(d: Date) { // remove type declaration and it will be ok.
        this.currentTime = d;
    }
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
}
```

Suppose in the class implementation we changed `setTime(d: Date) {` with just `setTime(d) {`. So now we didn't fully implement  `ClockInterface`, but TypeScript doesn't warn us about that. And if we use IntelliSense there will be just **any** in the type suggestion:

```
new Clock(3,5).setTime("d: any") // <-- not implemented
```

so why doesn't compiler warn us?

Comment: Most probably because if setTime() accepts anything, it also accepts a Date, and thus does implement the interface: you can call setTime(someDate) on a Clock.

Comment: @JBNizet but method setTime() works only with dates, so why do we need interfaces at all if we could marked all arguments as any. I thougth that interfaces is needed exactly for that reason.

Comment: That's not what the interface says. The interfaces say: "all classes implementing this interface must have a setTime method accepting a Date, and a currentTime field which must be of type Date". The two are unrelated. And Clock implements that interface. Now if yourClock.setTime took a string as argument, it would be different, because a method only accepting string as argument doesn't accept a Date, and thus doesn't fulfil the contract of the interface.

Comment: Also, TS doesn't warn you about assigning an any to a Date because any basically means: I choose to opt out of type checking, I know better than you, please don't bother.

Comment: @JBNizet I got your idea. Though I didn't catch about took a string and what is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so why doesn't compiler warn us?

Because `any` is compatible with all types: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html#any

## noImplicitAny

To prevent your self getting caught off guard use `noImplicitAny` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/options/noImplicitAny.html

```
interface ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date;
    setTime(d: Date);
}

class Clock implements ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date;
    setTime(d) { // ERROR : implicit Any
        this.currentTime = d;
    }
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly from typescript [specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#811-class-heritage-specification)

> Note that because TypeScript has a structural type system, a class doesn't need to explicitly state that it implements an interface—it suffices for the class to simply contain the appropriate set of instance members. The `implements` clause of a class provides a mechanism to assert and validate that the class contains the appropriate sets of instance members, but otherwise it has no effect on the class type.

I think it answers your question quite well.